pynput mouse listener is not working on python 3.13.0
I am trying to get mouse click event from the listener of the pynput package, but it's not working.
def init_listeners(self):
    try:
        self.mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(
            on_move=self.on_move,
            on_click=self.on_click,
            on_scroll=self.on_scroll
        )
        self.keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=self.on_press,
            on_release=None
        )

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error initializing listeners: {e}")
        self.mouse_listener = None
        self.keyboard_listener = None

Getting this error:
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 386, in _handler
    converted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 401, in _convert
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

python version is 3.13.0
I tried it on version 3.11.3, it is working well, but on 3.13.0 it is not working.
Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

There is a defect in pynput for Python 3.13. The bug is reported here.
